# How to choose year,month,day,hour,minute from UIdatepicker

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

The UIDatePickerMode has:
UIDatePickerModeTime can choose hour and minute
UIDatePickerModeDate can choose month,day,year
UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime can choose week month hour minute
UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer can choose hour and minute
but none of those can choose all year ,month,day,hour and minute?Can I do that in one datepicker?thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't achieve that using UIDatePicker.

You need to create your own custom date picker using [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/)

You need to implement the following picker delegate and data source methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;

- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```